# PayPal JS SDK loading in sandbox mode with live clientid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal

So I changed the client id of my PayPal SDK to the live client id but it's still loading in sandbox mode and doesn't accept payments from real PayPal accounts

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiW9z.png)

Comment: Does [this](https://developer.paypal.com/reference/production/) answer your question?

Comment: is there a video tutorial for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *only* explanation for what is shown in the screenshot is you must actually be using a sandbox clientid value (either your own sandbox account, or `test`) somewhere on the page. Inspect it in your browser's developer tools or network tab and you will find the actual URL the script is being loaded with.

If you still aren't to resolve this, you need to include a full sample or other way to reproduce the issue in your question.

Comment: I'm using the live client id tho there aren't any sandbox client id in my code

Comment: Try your clientid at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client . If it works there, there's a problem with your code or page using a different one. That's all that can be said with the lack of debugging information in this question

Comment: I tried it and it's not on sandbox mode anymore

Comment: It said that i can't connect to the sellers account tho

Comment: Nvm i tried it with my code and it worked now